# Validation of multiple table fields using Dynamic Rule

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I have a dynamic table, which each row contains country and numberOfState fields.  Currently I am able to add new record and validate the country and numberOfState field separately (e.g. required) after click the "AddNewRecord" button, which is below code that generate dynamic table unique field name, i.e. name="country_0", "numberOfState_0" for 1st row, and ="country_1", "numberOfState_1" for 2nd row and etc.

Would like to check whether can validate the dynamic country and numberOfState fields together (i.e. Country is US and NumberOfState must be 50), using dynamic rule code as per below addRowRule function. Thanks in advance.

```
     $(document).ready(function(e){
            var rowindex = 0;

            $("#AddNewRecord").click(function(){
                var row = 
                    "<tr><td>input name=country_"+rowindex+" type=text class='countryRule'/></td>
                     <tr><td>input name=numberOfState_"+rowindex+" type=text class='stateRule'/></td></tr>";
                $("#table").append(row);
                rowindex++;
                addRowRule(rowindex);
            });

           jQuery.validate.addClassRules({
                countryRule:{required:true},
                stateRule:{required:true}
            });

            $('form').validate();


    function addRowRule(i) {     
    var country = '#country_' + i,
    var numberOfState = '#numberOfState_' + i;

    $(country).rules('add', {
        required: true,
        numberOfState:{              
          required: {
             depend: function(element){
                  if ($(country).val() == 'US' &&     
                       $(numberOfState).val() !=50){
                           return false;
                  }
                  return true;
             }
             messages: {
                numberOfState: "Number of state not match with country",
             }
          },
          messages: {
                required: "Required input",
             }    
    });
});
```

***Updated code to share with all:***

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
     $("#myForm").validate(); //sets up the validator

     var rowindex = 0;
     $("#AddNewRecord").click(function(){
         var row = "<tr><td>input name=country_"+rowindex+" type=text /></td>" +
                "<tr><td>input name=numberOfState_"+rowindex+" type=text /></td></tr>";
         $("#table").append(row);
         addRowRule(rowindex);
         rowindex++;     
     });

     function addRowRule(row_index) {     
        var country = '#country_' + row_index;
        var numberOfState = '#numberOfState_' + row_index;

        $(country).rules('add', {
            required: true,
            messages: {
                required: "Pls input country."
            }
        });

        $(numberOfState).rules('add', {
            required: true,
            checkCountryAndState: [country, numberOfState],
            messages: {
                required: "Pls input number of state."
            }
        });
     }

     jQuery.validator.addMethod("checkCountryAndState", function(value, element, params){
         var varCountry = params[0];
         var varNumberOfState = params[1];
         if ($(varCountry).val() === 'America' && $(varNumberOfState).val() !== 50){
            return false;
         }
         return true;
     }, jQuery.format("Country is not match with Number of State."));

});
```

Comment: Refer to the official docs: http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate Especially to the `messages` and `rules` properties.

Comment: Meskobalazs, I know how to use rules and message validation for validate multiple fields, but that the rule field names is without row subscript, so how can jquery pickup the particular row for validation ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can specify validation rules with the `rules` property. This should do what you specified in the question as an example:

```
$(".selector").validate({
    rules: {
        field2: {
            required: true,
            field1: {
                depends: function(element) {
                    if ($('#field1').val() === 'A' && $('#field2').val() === 'Z') {
                        return false;
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

After this, you need to assign a message if the validation fails with the `messages` property.

Comment: Thanks so much Meskobalazs.  Was wondering why the rule does not need to specify the subscript of table row, as there are mutliple table row with field1 and field2 names. is that the ".selector" allow jquery to validate the row that i click on the save button class ? Thanks.

Comment: @Leanne, you must have a ***unique*** `name` on every input within the `form`.

Comment: @Sparky, Refer to my code in question, I have included subscript var rowindex for field1 and field2 which is unique and can validate individual fields for each row. But, not sure how to validate multiple related fields at once. Spending whole day but not able to find an answer thru jquery doc and internet, really need advice from expert here.  Do you know how ?  Thanks

Comment: @Leanne, your question/issue is very unclear.  What does *"how to validate multiple related fields at once"* mean?

Comment: @Leanne, yes, they are unique.  Please, we should not be having a discussion in comments.  Edit your question to make it more clear.  Explain more details about what is going wrong.  Show your `.validate()` method and the rest of the relevant `form` markup.

Answer (score 0):

Part of your problem is putting invalid objects inside of the `.rules()` method.  Since the `.rules()` method is already ***attached*** to a selector (representing a SINGLE field), you cannot declare rules for additional fields inside of it...

```
function addRowRule(i) {    

    var country = '#country_' + i,
    var numberOfState = '#numberOfState_' + i;

    $(country).rules('add', {
        required: true,
        numberOfState: {  // <- you can NOT put this here       
            required: { ...
```

The only objects allowed inside of `.rules()` is a `key: value` list of various rules/methods and/or the `messages` object.

You would have to attach other fields to different instances of `.rules()`....

```
function addRowRule(i) {  

    var country = '#country_' + i,
    var numberOfState = '#numberOfState_' + i;

    $(country).rules('add', {
        required: true,
        ....
    });

    $(numberOfState).rules('add', {
        required: true,
        ....
    });  
    ....
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback.  I have changed above code, is that correct now and able to validate country=America and numberOfState must be 50 for each table row ?

Comment: @Leanne, it looked correct to me.  However, I rolled back your OP to the previous version because if you keep fixing it to match the answers, then the the whole thing becomes meaningless to future readers.  You should create a jsFiddle and/or ***append*** the OP with any new information.

Comment: Sparky, Thanks so much for your advice.  Just to confirm that "checkCountryAndState: [country, numberOfState]" statement is correct syntax for the checkCountryAndState rule method which receive list of object parameter values right, where country and numberOfState object values are "#country_0", and is "#numberOfState_0" respectively?  Newbie here, will post the updated code later =).

Comment: @Leanne, your syntax for passing multiple parameters into custom method is correct.